# Ignore child object except specifically-mapped properties

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is there a way to configure a MapStruct mapping to ignore a child object, but still map a specific property on the child?

For example:

```java
@Mapper
interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "organization", ignore = true) // ignore organization
    @Mapping(source = "organizationId", target = "organization.id") // except organization.id
    Person toEntity(PersonModel model);
}
```

This way, the target `organization` is non-null and has the `id` field set from the source's `organizationId` field. Currently, this approach seems to give priority to the ignored child `organization` and the property is left as `null`.

Note: I'm looking to do this without having to implement a custom mapping method (e.g. just using annotations).

Comment: can't you ignore on the same level as (so the sub properties of organisation)..

Comment: another option would be to add  a `@BeanMapping` annotation with the option ignore all = true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to achieve what you are looking for without adding an additional mapping method with annotations.

When

```
@Mapping(target = "organization", ignore = true)
```

is used then no matter what you do with the nested mappings for `organization`, the entire property `organization` is ignored.

However, you can achieve what you need if you do the following:

```
@Mapper
interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "organization", source = "model"
    Person toEntity(PersonModel model);

    @BeanMaping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "organizationId")
    Organization toOrganizationEntity(PersonModel model)
}
```

What did we just do now:

1. We added a custom `toOrganizationEntity` model from `PersonModel` to `Organization`
2. We said that we are mapping the source parameter for model (from the toEntity) into the organization
3. We are ignoring all properties for the target mapping in the `toOrganizationEntity`
4. We are explicitly mapping the `organizationId` into the `id` of the `Organization`.

In  case you don't want to expose a public method on your `PersonMapper` interface you can use an abstract class instead.

```
@Mapper
public class PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "organization", source = "model"
    public abstract Person toEntity(PersonModel model);

    @BeanMaping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "organizationId")
    protected abstract Organization toOrganizationEntity(PersonModel model)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.